# Java SimpleDateFormat parsing issue

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a date string I got out of a website in Java using the SimpleDateFormat class, but something goes wrong and I can't figure out why.

The date strings come in the following syntax:

```
"13:37 - Tue 28-Jun-2011"
```

So I tried doing the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm - EEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);   
Date d = dateFormat.parse("13:37 - Tue 28-Jun-2011", pos);
```

As I said before, this doesn't work; when I print

```
System.out.println(pos.getErrorIndex());
```

it prints "8", which I assume means that the error is somewhere around the EEE part. I've tried different permutations but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

bompf

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what error does it show?

Comment: Could you actually please post that locale-thing as a solution to this question and then accept your own answer? It'd help the rest of us.

Comment: I have done as you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I did not know I have to set a locale for the date format..

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm - EEE dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This works now!

Answer (score 2):

If your trying to parse the date this will work. I dont know what you are trying to do with `ParsePosition`

```
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm - EEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
   Date d = dateFormat.parse("13:37 - Tue 28-Jun-2011");
   System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me...

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm - EEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);   
Date d = dateFormat.parse("13:37 - Tue 28-Jun-2011", pos);

System.out.println(pos.getErrorIndex());
System.out.println(d);
```

Output -

```
-1
Tue Jun 28 13:37:00 EDT 2011
```